# Inserting Record Through Loop

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a form in which values comes from database, all input fields have their own name and they are looped. When i submit form the data insert's as equals to the loop in each cell of each row :(

**Here is the screenshot** (*to explain properly*)

[image]

**Here is the Form Where i looped the records from it.**

```
<%
While Not RStmtbl.EOF
%>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("tdate"))%>" name="tdate_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("day"))%>" name="day_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("class"))%>" name="class_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("pno"))%>" name="pno_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("subject"))%>" name="subject_insert" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("teacher"))%>" name="teacher_insert" readonly /></td>
<td>
<select name="status_insert">
<option selected>Choose Status</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" value="<% Response.Write(formno) %>" name="uid_insert">
<input type="hidden" value="<% Response.Write(Now) %>" name="sdate_insert">
</td>
</tr>
<%
RStmtbl.Movenext
Wend
%>
```

**Here is the Insert Code**

```
<%
if request.Form("TcfRecord")="Insert" then
Set InsCom=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
InsCom.ActiveConnection=objConn

InsTD = Trim(request.Form("tdate_insert"))
InsTD = replace(InsTD,"'","''")

InsTD2 = Trim(request.Form("day_insert"))
InsTD2 = replace(InsTD2,"'","''")

InsCL = Trim(request.Form("class_insert"))
InsCL = replace(InsCL,"'","''")

InsPI = Trim(request.Form("pno_insert"))
InsPI = replace(InsPI,"'","''")

InsSBI = Trim(request.Form("subject_insert"))
InsSBI = replace(InsSBI,"'","''")

InsTI = Trim(request.Form("teacher_insert"))
InsTI = replace(InsTI,"'","''")

InsSI = Trim(request.Form("status_insert"))
InsSI = replace(InsSI,"'","''")

InsUI = Trim(request.Form("uid_insert"))
InsUI = replace(InsUI,"'","''")

InsDI = Trim(request.Form("sdate_insert"))
InsDI = replace(InsDI,"'","''")

For Each item in Request.Form
InsCom.CommandText = "Insert into time_table_status(tdate, [day], [class], pno, subject, teacher, status, uid, submit_date)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@tdate_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTD)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@day_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTD2)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@class_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsCL)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@pno_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsPI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@subject_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsSBI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@teacher_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@status_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsSI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@uid_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsUI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@sdate_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsDI)

InsCom.Execute

Next

end if
%>
```

There should be one value in each cell of each row. Please help me identify the error ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your form-building code should be something like this :

```
<%
Dim counter : counter = 1
While Not RStmtbl.EOF
%>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("tdate"))%>" name="tdate_insert_<%=counter%>" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("day"))%>" name="day_insert_<%=counter%>"  readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("class"))%>" name="class_insert_<%=counter%>"  readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("pno"))%>" name="pno_insert_<%=counter%>"  readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("subject"))%>" name="subject_insert_<%=counter%>"  readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<% Response.Write(Rstmtbl("teacher"))%>" name="teacher_insert_<%=counter%>"  readonly /></td>
<td>
<select name="status_insert_<%=counter%>">
<option selected>Choose Status</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" value="<% Response.Write(formno) %>" name="uid_insert_<%=counter%>">
<input type="hidden" value="<% Response.Write(Now) %>" name="sdate_insert_<%=counter%>">
</td>
</tr>
<%
RStmtbl.Movenext
counter =counter+1
Wend
%>
<input type="hidden" value="<% =counter%>" name="rowcount">
```

and then in your save page:

```
<%
if request.Form("TcfRecord")="Insert" then
Dim maxcount : maxcount = Cint(Request("rowcount"))
Dim counter 

for counter =1 to maxcount-1 

Set InsCom=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
InsCom.ActiveConnection=objConn

InsTD = Trim(request.Form("tdate_insert_" & CStr(counter ) ))
InsTD = replace(InsTD,"'","''")

InsTD2 = Trim(request.Form("day_insert_" & CStr(counter ) ))
InsTD2 = replace(InsTD2,"'","''")

InsCL = Trim(request.Form("class_insert_" & CStr(counter ) ))
InsCL = replace(InsCL,"'","''")

InsPI = Trim(request.Form("pno_insert_"&  CStr(counter ) ))
InsPI = replace(InsPI,"'","''")

InsSBI = Trim(request.Form("subject_insert_"&  CStr(counter ) ))
InsSBI = replace(InsSBI,"'","''")

InsTI = Trim(request.Form("teacher_insert_" & CStr(counter ) ))
InsTI = replace(InsTI,"'","''")

InsSI = Trim(request.Form("status_insert_" & CStr(counter ) ))
InsSI = replace(InsSI,"'","''")

InsUI = Trim(request.Form("uid_insert_"& CStr(counter ) ))
InsUI = replace(InsUI,"'","''")

InsDI = Trim(request.Form("sdate_insert_" & CStr(counter ) ))
InsDI = replace(InsDI,"'","''")


InsCom.CommandText = "Insert into time_table_status(tdate, [day], [class], pno, subject, teacher, status, uid, submit_date)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@tdate_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTD)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@day_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTD2)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@class_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsCL)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@pno_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsPI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@subject_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsSBI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@teacher_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsTI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@status_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsSI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@uid_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsUI)
InsCom.Parameters.Append InsCom.CreateParameter("@sdate_insert", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, InsDI)

InsCom.Execute

Next

end if
%>
```

i don't  have a asp-enabled machine to run this and check for errors right now, but that is the general idea.

please post if you have issues.

Comment: Awesome Job, everything works perfectly, 1 issue though, 1st row inserts empty other than form data. (May be this is causing by the hidden rowcount field)

Comment: i missed to add the counter to your `status_insert` dropdown. Other than that, can't see why a blank row should get inserted ..

Comment: please check myedits, changed the loop to `for counter =1 to maxcount-1 `

Comment: yes, i saw that when i inserted record first time. the status_insert record was missing then i  added the `<%=counter%>` part. After changing the loop `for counter =1 to maxcount-1` it works fine.

Comment: Thanks alot SearchAndResQ :)